# How to connect apach solr with opencart

Tags: solr, opencart

i am new to apache solr

apache solr i download solr6.5.1 whith in my core folder i add the and add data-config.xml

```
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
                  driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                  url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/opencart"
                  user="root"
                  password=""/>
```

solrconfig.xml

```
<requestHandlername="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

schema.xml

```
<field name="catids" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/> <field name="manuids" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

---

i try to data import i am not abul to import

Comment: Where is your sql definition?

Comment: mysql in my xampp server  localhost/phpmyadmin